# "not a proper statistics file" when reading sar log files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring

Why am I getting "not a proper statistics file" when reading sar log files?

```
sysstat Version: 11.2.0-1ubuntu0.2

root@sandbox1:/var/log/sysstat# ls -lh

total 4.5K

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.9K Jul 12 06:17 sa12

root@sandbox1:/var/log/sysstat# sar -u -f sa12

Not a proper statistics file
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the file is in a binary format you can convert it with:

```
sar -A -f sarlog.bin > sarlog.ascii
```

Comment: root@sandbox1:/var/log/sysstat# sar -A -f sa12 > sarlog
Not a proper statistics file
root@sandbox1:/var/log/sysstat# cat sarlog 
root@sandbox1:/var/log/sysstat#

Comment: the sysstat package on centos 6 machine works fine

Comment: sysstat-9.0.4-33.el6_9.1.x86_64 is running on Centos6

Comment: what does `head -5 sa12` show, and also what does `file sa12` show?

Comment: The output is garbled and it seems to be a data file `root@sandbox1:~# file /var/log/sysstat/sa12 
/var/log/sysstat/sa12: data`